# Image manipulation with Node for a Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to insert an image in another image.

One is the template and the other one is the source.
The template image has a rectangular transparent area and I want to insert my source image to fit that transparent area.

Is this possible with Javascript?

Comment: yes, everything is possible with javascript.

Comment: use the canvas html tag with javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use sharp in node to do the image processing:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp